# Django Translation Issue

Tags: django

I have the following in my **settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE='es-US'
USE_I18N = True
```

and I also have **django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware** in my **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** Tuple.

Is this configuration enough to see Base Django Error messages in Spanish or is there more to it?

Somehow my messages still keep showing in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the Django Base Error in Spanish, you need to set Spanish as your active language.

To make sure which is your active language you can add in your template:

```
{{request.session.django_language}} 

{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}
```

and to see your active language in a view:

```
django.utils.translation.get_language()
```

I recomend you to have a sample view like next example to change between languages.

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^set_language/(?P<language_code>[\w-]+)/?', 'yourapp.views.set_language', name='set_language'),
```

**views.py**

```
def set_language(request, language_code):
    ''' Change language '''

    request.session['django_language'] = language_code
    translation.activate(language_code)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I also strongly recommend you to check this Django APP for translation:

- [Django-Rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta)

There is also a tutorial to make the translation works, and this app makes very easy to translate the texts you mark for translation